# Can't make a search based on input value using fetched data . Getting a filter error

Tags: javascript, rest, webpack, fetch, handlebars.js

Attempting to make an inquiry which depends on input esteem. I am utilizing countries rest programming interface. The wished yield is the parsed information from API which is templated by handlebars markup. It would be ideal if you clarify in what capacity can fix my code. Much obliged to you.

```
import markupAdd from "../templates/markup.hbs";
const divInfo = document.querySelector("#main-container");
const search_input = document.querySelector(".input-field");
let search_term = "";
let countries;


const fetchCountries = () => {
  countries = fetch(
    "https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all?fields=name;flag;capital;population;languages"
  ).then((res) => res.json());
};

const showCountries = () => {
  divInfo.innerHTML = "";
  fetchCountries();
  countries
    .filter((country) =>
      country.name.toLowerCase().includes(search_term.toLowerCase())
    )
    .map((item) => markupAdd(item))
    .join("");
  divInfo.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", infoBlock);
};

search_input.addEventListener("input", (e) => {
  search_term = e.target.value;
  showCountries();
});
```

handlebars

```
<div id="country-container">
    <p class="country">{{name}}</p>
    <img src="{{flag}}" alt="{{name}}" width="600" height="400">
    <div id="info-container">
        <p class="capital">Capital: {{capital}}</p>
        <p class="population">Population: {{population}} </p>
        <ul class="langs">
            {{#each languages}}
            <li class="language">Languages: {{name}}</li>
            {{/each}}
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

At the present time, after inputed any letter I am getting this kind of error

```
apiInfo.js?b765:22 Uncaught TypeError: countries.filter is not a function
    at showCountries (apiInfo.js?b765:22)
    at HTMLInputElement.eval (apiInfo.js?b765:28)
```

Comment: because `fetchCountries` is not returning an array, its returning undefined

Comment: Check how to use async and await. It will help here

Comment: @blacksheep could you please help what should I change?

Comment: @HarmandeepSinghKalsi i have included it right now....still no result

Comment: Try this: make `fetchCountries` async: `const fetchCountries = async ()  =>` then  in `showCountries()` replace `fetchCountries()` with `countries = await fetchCountries()` then in next line replace `countries.filter(...` with `countries = countries.filter(...`

Comment: @SonNguyen Is it possible to refactor the code without using async/await?

Comment: @ElMuchacho Yes but it's a bit tricky with `fetchCountries`. either create a `Promise` to return it or move the model update logic into the function. See the accepted solution for the latter approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fetchCounries` function is not returning anything, one approch to solve the issue will be following.

- Convert the Function to the `async` function
- and then return the data your will get.

```js
const fetchCountries = async () => {
  let countries = await fetch(
    "https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all?fields=name;flag;capital;population;languages"
  );
  let country =  await countries.json();
  return country;
};

const showCountries = () => {
  divInfo.innerHTML = "";
  fetchCountries().then(countries =>{
    countries
    .filter((country) =>
      country.name.toLowerCase().includes(search_term.toLowerCase())
    )
    .map((item) => markupAdd(item))
    .join("");
    divInfo.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", infoBlock);
  }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
  })
};
```

Async Function also returns  a promise so later you can handle this using then catch block

to do it without the async await and do it more clear, you can do something like this

```
const fetchCountries = () => {
  fetch(
    "https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all?fields=name;flag;capital;population;languages"
  )
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
      showCountries(data);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
};

const showCountries = (countries) => {
  divInfo.innerHTML = "";
  countries
    .filter((country) =>
      country.name.toLowerCase().includes(search_term.toLowerCase())
    )
    .map((item) => markupAdd(item))
    .join("");
  divInfo.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", infoBlock);
};
```

Comment: Is it possible to refactor the code without using async/await?

Comment: Yes you could but you will have to move the stuff inside the `showCountries` inside the `.then` block of the `fetch` function. because the data returned by the function is only avilable there.

Comment: could you please help with refactoring?

Comment: i added, tak a look

Comment: could you please help with explaining the sequence? why the code didn't work without async/await?

Answer (score 1):

Change your function like this :

```
async function fetchCountries() {
  response = await fetch ("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all?fields=name;flag;capital;population;languages");
return await response.json();
};
```

And where you are calling the function , just use .then to get the data.

```
fetchCountries().then().catch();
```

Comment: Is it possible to refactor the code without using async/await?

Comment: Yes you can do that . The code for filtering will go inside the fetchCountries function .

Comment: I think you got the answer already. Happy Learning!

Comment: Thank you so much...! but i actually still not sure why it didn't worked out without async...could you please help?